# jQuery switching between images

Tags: jquery, html, css, fadein, fadeout

I have a small script here to switch between 2 images... It works like if you select 1st it stay selected, if you select 2nd - 1st one is fading out and 2nd is being selected... Simple like that.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".theImage img").click(function () {
        var a = $(this).parent().attr("id") == "product-holder1" ? "product-holder2" : "product-holder1";
        console.log(a);
        $(this).fadeOut();
        $("#" + a + " img").fadeIn()
    })
})
```

My problem is that I don't know how do I use it for more then 2 images?
Let's say I have id "product-holder3" and maybe "product-holder4" so how do I write this in that jquery code, so it still switch between which one is being selected?

**HTML:**

```html
<div id="product-holder1" class="theImage">
  <img src="img/10-normal.png" />
</div>
<div id="product-holder2" class="theImage">
  <img src="img/25-normal.png" />
</div>
    <div id="product-holder3" class="theImage">
  <img src="img/50-normal.png" />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
#product-holder1 {
    background: url("img/10-selected.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 182px;
    width: 195px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    left: 62px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#product-holder2 {
    background: url("img/25-selected.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 182px;
    width: 195px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    left: 124px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#product-holder3 {
    background: url("img/50-selected.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 182px;
    width: 195px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    left: 186x;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Just please tell me how to use it for product-holder3 and maybe one day I need for more images, so please let me know how that works? Thanks a lot!

P.S I don't know anything about jQuery :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an update based upon discussion in the comments below:

```
// Listen for the click event of our many containers
$(".theImage").on("click", function(){
   // In the event clicked, find image, fade slowly to .01 opacity
   $(this).find("img").fadeTo("slow",0).end()
     // Then, of siblings, find all images and fade slowly to 100% opacity
     .siblings().find("img").fadeTo("slow",1);           
});​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/yvM8Z/2/

Comment: I have added $(document).ready(function () { on top of your script and instead of }); I have added }) and below }) again... It works sort of but instead of if one image is selected and click on another fades it out... its like "Click=Selected, Click= selected again, Click=One fades out and select" so its like 2 images being selected all the time while third is fading out...

Comment: @NenaddvL Just so I understand: When you click on an image, you want that image to fade out, and the image in the next product-holder to fade in, correct?

Comment: Ok my English aint awesome... So let's do it like this.

Image 1, Image 2, Image 3.

Page is loaded and I am clicking one image (example image 2). It fades in as selected.

I am changing my mind and clicking another image... previously selected image (image 2) fades out while the new one that I clicked (fades in)

Comment: @NenaddvL How do you click an image that is not already visible?

Comment: No not like these cats... That is one image in spot fades in/out...

Ok like this... Three images are already visible. Click on each just replace the image with another one so image changes background like its being selected... 

So basically 3 images, all three are visible, but click on each changes them as selected. :D Don't know how to explain easier... Script on the top works perfectly... so  I guess you can find out from it what I need... same thing just for one or two more images to add inside for switching.

Comment: @NenaddvL Let me try this again with that information. Thank you.

Comment: Just a small lil' thingy... Click on one image = fadesIn , click on another = fadesIn but previous fadesOut... I tried your script and it works perfectly except that images arent being fadedOut... Just switched without effect... ;) ! Thanks so much if you can fix that small problem, if not Ill stick to switch without fading out effect.

Comment: Thats correct but fades out doesnt works... If you cannot fix, no problems. I'll use it like that.

Comment: Sorry, I'm having difficulty understanding. The images *are* fading out: http://jsfiddle.net/yvM8Z/2/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11757/discussion-between-nenad-dvl-and-jonathan-sampson)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a collection that contains the container div's you are cycling through (or at least their ids').  Something like `$(".theImage img:parent")` if you don't need to worry about manipulating the cycling order.  Then in your click function you can look up the current collection element using the id from `$(this).parent().attr("id")` and then get it's index.  Once you know the index you can move to the next item in the collection (or wrap to the beginning if you're at the end) and get the new id, setting that as the value of your variable `a`.